# pandas groupby sum area plot

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm looking to make a stacked area plot over time, based on summary data created by groupby and sum.

The groupby and sum part correctly groups and sums the data I want, but it seems the resultant format is nonsense in terms of plotting it.

I'm not sure where to go from here:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    df=pd.DataFrame({'invoice':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'year':[2016,2016,2017,2017,2017,2017],'part':['widget','wonka','widget','wonka','wonka','wonka'],'dollars':[10,20,30,10,10,10]})
    #drop the invoice number from the data since we don't need it
    df=df[['dollars','part','year']]
    #group by year and part, and add them up
    df=df.groupby(['year','part']).sum()

    #plotting this is nonsense:
    df.plot.area()
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to chart multiple series, its easiest to have each series organized as a separate column, i.e. replace

```
df=df.groupby(['year','part']).sum()
```

with

```
df=df.groupby(['year', 'part']).sum().unstack(-1)
```

Then the rest of the code should work. But, I'm not sure if this is what you need because the desired output is not shown.

`df.plot.area()` then produces the chart like

[image: area chart: <code>df.plot.area()</code>]